# Clustering with different size groups

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, networkx

I have a `defaultdict()` with an instance (represented by the key) and IDs that interact in that instance. These groups vary in size:

```
{
'2450-66-L116': {'7652', '8089', '9687', '7298', '7622'},
'2089-48-LQ16': {'7628', '1269', '96664', '76493'},
'2827-176-LE16': {'76538', '1269', '6688', '7990', '7649'},
'2322-153-L116': {'1588', '8460', '7606', '15745'},
'4063-1-LE16': {'9339', '8682'},
'2142-9-L116': {'7990', '7684', '9687'},
'608-664-LE16': {'7610'},
'2789-204-L116': {'8089', '5782', '96664', '7990'},
'994-31-L116': {'15745', '7610'},
'994-35-LE16': {'12569', '7802'},
'1559-1080-L115': {'7652', '8682', '7607', '9675', '7614', '7802', '7610'},
'5326-30-L116': {'9687', '7684', '7652', '5782', '7638', '5907', '7663'}
}
```

I need to create groups of IDs that usually interact in the same instances. What would be the best way of creating ID clusters with this data? Should I use kmeans, networkx, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, working with dictionaries when doing any modelisation is definitely not good. 
you should create an array or a pandas dataframe with id as label and all your instances as variables (they should have 0 or 1 if they are linked to an ID).
then you can try building a kmeans but I'm not sure you have anough data to build anything...

Comment: Thanks! The original data is composed of 43K IDs and 110K instances. Ok, I do have a dataframe with 1 and 0s but it crashes sometimes doing other operations so that is why I turned it into a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure any sciki-learn algorithms accept dictionaries so you should go back to your dataframe. What is wrong with it ? Why does it crash ?